# .htaccess redirect but show different URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want my site to act like this. If user inputs `site.cz` it should be redirected to `site.eu/?lang=cs` but the user should still see `site.cz`. Right now I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site\.cz [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://site.eu/?lang=cs [L,R=301]
```

which works great and redirects only .cz request (dont do anything with .eu requests) but it displays `.eu/?lang=cs` in final. Problem is that I dont only want to display site.cz all the time but also links like `site.eu/folder1/file1/?lang=cs` should be redirected to `site.cz/folder1/file1/`

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks in forward

Comment: You cant use the `R` flag and not expect it to do what it's supposed to which is `Redirect`. So yes, you will see the .eu url in the browser because you told it to redirect. You need to look at using `mod_proxy` or `[P]` flag.

Comment: when I use [P] flag I get an error "Following URL was not found on this server"

Comment: You need to make sure mod_proxy is enabled.

Comment: ok, so lets say that this will solve and issue of displaying root web address but what about other pages? Like I said every link is configured to have ?lang=cs param at the end and it points to auto-flex.eu but I want it to show auto-flex.cz/products/product1 for example instead of auto-flex.eu/products/products1/?lang=cs how should I accomplish that

Comment: You don't seem to be stating clearly on what you want. You sound like you  have a bunch of mixed links and want some to redirect but not others. If all the links on the page already have ?lang=cs param why are you trying to redirect it? I'm not understanding what you want.

Comment: I will try to explain it. I have 2 domains .eu and .cz. Right now it is setup that if I enter .cz it gets redirected to .eu/?lang=cs which is not wanted but I should solve it with P flag like you mentioned. On the other hand what I want is that when I click on link on cz page I want it to change to structure that I mentioned because right now it show .eu/clicked/link/?lang=cs but I want it to show .cz/clicked/link/?lang=cs

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XAMPP or a web host? Upon testing, URL rewriting isn't working in XAMPP.. Anyway, you can try to check this, just make sure that your two sites are hosted by the same web hosting account:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site\.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.eu/$1?lang=cs [P,L]
```

But it looks like your sites aren't hosted by the same hosting account as what you've said:

> when I use [P] flag I get an error "Following URL was not found on this server" –  horin